# Google Maps API - Uncaught Error: Module: 'earth' not found

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-chrome

My web page using the Google Maps API stopped working, it showed this warning

> "Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages#sensor-not-required"  util.js:210:33

I have removed the "sensor" parameter from my script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyDUfHlQGcDOJ4MUcEdhBaIs0Qvs80Fmes4"></script>
```

Then it marked the error on this line:

```
google.load("earth", "1.x");
```

Since yesterday I'm looking at help forums and I have not been able to find the solution.

[image: screenshot of error message]

Answer (score 1):

[The Google Earth API is no longer available.](https://developers.google.com/earth/)

[Blog Announcement](https://maps-apis.googleblog.com/2014/12/announcing-deprecation-of-google-earth.html)

**From the blog:**

> we have decided to retire the Google Earth API. Per our deprecation policy, 
>   the API will be supported until one year from today and will be turned off on 
>   December 12, 2015.